# How to remove button style?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I need to send a POST to a controller action, so I have this:

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" role="form">
      <div>                
        <button type="submit">
            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </li>
```

However, the button has a style and I need to have it a style with a transparent background and no border so that it mimics a standard icon.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the classes `"border-0"` & `"bg-transparent"`

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" role="form">
    <div>
      <button type="submit" class="border-0  bg-transparent">
        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</li>
```

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/borders/#subtractive
- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/colors/#background-color